# Does Dask communicate with HDFS to optimize for data locality?

Tags: hdfs, dask, dask-distributed

In Dask distributed [documentation](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-dask-handle-data-locality), they have the following information:

> For example Dask developers use this ability to build in data locality
>   when we communicate to data-local storage systems like the Hadoop File
>   System. When users use high-level functions like
>   dask.dataframe.read_csv('hdfs:///path/to/files.*.csv') Dask talks to
>   the HDFS name node, finds the locations of all of the blocks of data,
>   and sends that information to the scheduler so that it can make
>   smarter decisions and improve load times for users.

However, it seems that the `get_block_locations()` was removed from the HDFS fs backend, so my question is: what is the current state of Dask regarding to HDFS ? Is it sending computation to nodes where data is local ? Is it optimizing the scheduler to take into account data locality on HDFS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite right, with the appearance of arrow's HDFS interface, which is now preferred over hdfs3, the consideration of block locations is no longer part of workloads accessing HDFS, since arrow's implementation doesn't include the get_block_locations() method.

However, we already wanted to remove the somewhat convoluted code which made this work, because we found that the inter-node bandwidth on test HDFS deployments was perfectly adequate that it made little practical difference in most workloads. The extra constrains on the size of the blocks versus the size of the partitions you would like in-memory created an additional layer of complexity.

By removing the specialised code, we could avoid the very special case that was being made for HDFS as opposed to external cloud storage (s3, gcs, azure) where it didn't matter which worker accessed which part of the data.

In short, yes the docs should be updated.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant, makes complete sense to me, maintaining fs backends with specialized code is not worth it.