# Accessing HDFS Data with Optimized Locality

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, fsspec

I am wondering, how to make sure HDFS data accessing makes the best use of the local replication to minimize the use of network transfer.

I am hosting HDFS on 3 machines and replication is set to 3. Let's name them machine A, B, C. Machine A is the namenode, and these 3 are all datanode.

Currently, I am reading data like the following code

```py
# Run this code on machine A, B, C separately
import fsspec
import pandas as pd
with fsspec.open('hdfs://machine_A_ip:9000/path/to/data.parquet', 'rb') as fp:
    df = pd.read_parquet(fp)
```

And I observed I have a huge traffic of network connection 100+MB/s upload and download. No matter I run on which machine (namenode or not).

I also tried hosting Dask and Ray cluster on the same machine set.
But I think Dask is not supporting this feature: [Does Dask communicate with HDFS to optimize for data locality? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565738/does-dask-communicate-with-hdfs-to-optimize-for-data-locality)

I haven't found clues in the documentations

- [API Reference — fsspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=HDFS#fsspec.implementations.arrow.HadoopFileSystem): Wraps pyarrow
- [pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem — Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem)
- [Filesystem Interface — Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#filesystem-hdfs)
- [Issues · apache/arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues?q=locality+): Seems no dicussion about locality

Answer (score 0):

Can explore Short Circuit Local Reads
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ShortCircuitLocalReads.html

Answer (score -1):

You are right, dask does not know where each file is in your cluster.  You would need to gather this information in some other manner; pyarrow, the current interface to HDFS does not surface this.